# Accessing a cv::Mat independently from its size

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I need to access a `cv::Mat`, but i don't have to know the `sizeof` the Matrix, so is there a way to access the elements of a `cv::Mat` for all the sizes? I mean without doing a switch on the type of the Matrix.

So this is what i have :

```
int image_type = image.type();
switch (image_type)
{
case CV_32F :
    return image.at<float>(i,j);
case CV_8U :
    return (float)image.at<uchar>(i,j);
.
.
.
default:
    std::string msg = "Exception : cannot access IMAGE of type : " + image_type;
    throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
    break;
}
```

what I'm doing is accessing the data of the matrix and then transform it to floats (since i work with matrix with 32F max), this code is working fine but I'm looking for something like this :
float x = image.at(i,j); but that would work for a matrix 8U and others ...

Thanks !

Comment: The matrix has `mat.rows` and `mat.cols`. But I think you mean the element type? You can interpret the element type with `mat.type()` or `.depth` and `.channels`.

Comment: I think that my question was not clear, I know that i can access the elements of the Matrix with .at<uchar> for 8c , .at<float> for 32F ... But what i need is a way to do it without doing a switch on the type of the Matrix.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted some code showing what you are currently doing ...

Comment: you can `.converTo` your Mat to a `float` Mat right in the beginning.

Comment: Well that's a good answer ! I'll try it

Comment: will give you some overhead, but should still be faster than your switch and typecast for each pixel ;) Alternative is to write your functions for each Mat type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you are asking, but obviously you would only want to call `convertTo()` once, not for every access.

```
Mat  dst;
image.convertTo(dst, CV_32F);
return dst.at<float>(i,j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation:

- The number of elements in a Mat is given by `Mat::total()`
- The number of rows, columns and channels are given by `Mat::rows`, `Mat::cols` and `Mat::channels()`, respectively.
- The type of data being held by the matrix is in `type()`

... and so on.

Read the documentation, and take a look to [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) on how to access matrix elements (**unless you use C++11 [type deduction](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html)** or something equivalent).

**EDIT:**

there is no way of accessing a Mat of unknown type without putting a *switch* statement somewhere.

Comment: I think that my question was not clear, I know that i can access the elements of the Matrix with .at<uchar> for 8c , .at<float> for 32F ... But what i need is a way to do it without doing a switch on the type of the Matrix.

Comment: If your question is not clear, you can always edit ;) Take a look to that tutorial.